# Wrong UICollectionView is loaded into Venue UITableviewCell when refreshed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am currently loading a UITableView with 4 cells fetched from Firebase (screen 1), each cell contains a UICollectionView to display the venue's images.

The problem is that when I refresh/reload the data by pulling-down to refresh the view (screen 2), the incorrect UICollectionView is loaded onto the 3rd cell's venue (screen 3)

**How can I ensure that the corresponding `UICollectionView` is loaded for the correct `Venue` `Cell`?**

[image]

Causing a **Fatal error: Index out of range** in `numberOfItemsInSection`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs.count

}
```

Here is my `cellForItemAt` func.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VenueListingCellImage", for: indexPath) as! VenueListingCellImage

    let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[indexPath.item]

    let imgURL = URL(string: urlString)

    cell.configureCell(url: imgURL!)

    return cell
}
```

Here is my `UITableView` `willDisplay` func.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //If cell has already been displayed it will just return
    if maxCellIndexAppeared > indexPath.row {
        return
    }
    //ELSE
    //here reset the current maximum index
    maxCellIndexAppeared = indexPath.row

    //animates the cell as it is being displayed for the first time
    cell.alpha = 1
    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -10, 0, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = transform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }

    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? VenueListingCell else { return }
    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)



}//end func
```

Comment: Where you set tag to collection view ?

Comment: in my `tableView` `willDisplay` function